# Angularjs ng-required call function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is possible make the required value dependet of some funcion?
Something like this? I want to do this because I want to change the required attribute to some form inputs...

HTML:

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"  ng-required="isRequired('name')" />
Age: <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"  ng-required="isRequired('age')" />
```

JS:

```
$scope.isRequired(fieldName){
         $scope.requiredFields = [];
         //$scope.requiredFields = STUFF FROM SOME REST SERVICE
        for (i in requiredFields) {
           if (requiredFields[i] == fieldName){
                return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Could you precisely describe what you want to do. And no its not possible but we could figure out another way

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi you can't. ng-required can only take a boolean.

Comment: I want to change if field is required or not, but I have too many fields and I was trying to create a function to check instead of creating a boolean for each fields in controller.

Comment: if you are willing to have a button, @tpie's answer does the trick for you

Comment: Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"  ng-required="isRequired('name')" />
Age: <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"  ng-required="isRequired('age')" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a couple of years old and so AngularJS may have changed, but the accepted answer as it stands today isn't correct. You can very easily execute a function within `ng-required`, as [it takes an expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired#ngRequired-arguments), which can be a function. For example:

## index.html

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController" class="expressions">
  Expression:
  <input type='text' ng-model="expr" size="80"/>
  <button ng-click="addExp(expr)">Evaluate</button>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="expr in exprs track by $index">
     [ <a href="" ng-click="removeExp($index)">X</a> ]
     <code>{{expr}}</code> => <span ng-bind="$parent.$eval(expr)"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## script.js

```
angular.module('expressionExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var exprs = $scope.exprs = [];
  $scope.expr = '3*10|currency';
  $scope.addExp = function(expr) {
    exprs.push(expr);
  };

  $scope.removeExp = function(index) {
    exprs.splice(index, 1);
  };
}]);
```

In `script.js`, a function `addExp` is defined and added to the scope, and then it's called in the `ng-click` directive of the `a` tag, which [also takes an expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick#ngClick-arguments) as its argument.

This code is taken directly from [the AngularJS documentation on expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). It doesn't use `ng-require` directly, but any directive that takes an expression will work the same. I have used the same syntax to use a function for `ng-require`.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer:**
So based on your updated OP, what you want is certainly doable.  The problem with what you were trying to do is that ng-required has no ability to execute a function, it only reads a boolean.  But we can dynamically create variables based on data from the server to automatically set fields to required:

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hdaT2ZTO5Sexo8Jduv1n?p=preview)

```
<form>
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.test"  ng-required="name" /><br/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"  ng-required="age" />
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that I put a $scope property for each input in the ng-required attribute.  Now we can dynamically create that $scope property and set it to true if our data says we need to:

```
  $scope.isRequired = function(){
         $scope.requiredFields = [];
         $http.get('fields.json')
         .success(function(data){
           $scope.requiredFields = angular.fromJson(data);
            console.log($scope.requiredFields.required)
           for (i = 0; i < $scope.requiredFields.required.length; i++) {
           $scope[$scope.requiredFields.required[i]] = true
            }
            console.log($scope[$scope.requiredFields.required[0]]);
         })

         //$scope.requiredFields = STUFF FROM SOME REST SERVICE

    }
    $scope.isRequired()
```

So it is iterating over an array of required fields received from the server, and then dynamically creating a $scope property for each one that is required, and setting it to true.  Any field that has that $scope property in it's ng-required will be required now.  Anything not dynamically created will just return false, and ng-required doesn't trigger.

---

Original answer:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MlVGfjkR0zlNxMyTrrzh?p=preview)

As Pratik mentioned, ng-required only accepts a **Boolean** value, but we can toggle the value of that with a function.

HTML

```
  <form>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"  ng-required="isRequired" />
    <br/><button ng-click="toggle()">Required: {{isRequired}}</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

code:

```
  $scope.isRequired = true;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.isRequired = !$scope.isRequired;
  }
```

Comment: It was what he thought. I need to create a boolean variable for each input field

Comment: This method is suitable if you want to disable and enable groups. You shouldn't create one boolean for each input.

Comment: If you have some special use case then you should outline it in the OP.  Unfortunately we don't know what you are doing, and so we can't help.  This would be the most obvious choice for a general use case (IMO).

Comment: I updated main post, I  realize that is not possible, I will try something different. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please include what it is you are trying to evaluate?  What you are trying to do in the OP can't be done, but it's still rather mysterious what you are trying to do.
What does the isRequired() function look like?

Comment: I updated the main post. It's not a blocking question, I was just wondering if this were possible. But I will validate required fields on Submit button. It was just a curiosity.

Comment: it's possible, but we wasted a fair bit of time simply because we didn't know what the real question was.

See my updated solution, which should accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: I'm Sorry for that. Your answear seems nice, I will use it.

Comment: hah well use it if it works! (and accept the answer).  If not, explain how the solution doesn't do what you need, or modify it yourself, etc.  
Just try to make your initial question as clear as possible.  The more information the better.

Comment: I wanted to address an early part of this answer, as it's incorrect: _"The problem with what you were trying to do is that ng-required has no ability to execute a function, it only reads a boolean."_ Actually, `ng-required` executes an _expression_, which can be a function call if that function is bound to the scope. See the second example at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression for that syntax.